# What does sanitize forbidden attributes error mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does it simply mean that I have a parameter in my 'model_params' variable that is not in this line?

```
params.require(...).permit(...)
```

I can't find offending parameter.  Is there a way to accept all parameters?

Comment: What does the error say and where do you get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can find offending parameters in rails server logs. It will tell you what params is not permitted
2. Yes, you can accept all parameters

   ```
   params.require(...).permit!
   ```

   You can check docs for [more info](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values)

Comment: Unpermitted parameters:    Brilliant!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to accept all parameters

Sure, just use `params[:whatever]` directly, without all that require/permit business.

But you should know that it's there for a reason: blindly accepting all user input is BAD. Your app should accept only the whitelisted parameters and ignore others.